# Purpose behind comparing string pointer to NULL as well as NULL character

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-platform

While trying to compile [`xtrabackup`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/installation.html) from [source](https://github.com/percona/percona-xtrabackup) I've found a peculiar line of code in `sql/sql_acl.cc` that GCC is refusing to compile without a more permissive setting. This line is the problem:

```
if (combo->plugin.str == NULL || combo->plugin.str == '\0')
```

Which immediately raises the following error:

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

This seems entirely reasonable given the code in question. The `plugin` value is of this type:

```
struct st_mysql_lex_string
{
  char *str;
  size_t length;
};
```

Where that's a simple MySQL internal structure that represents a string pointer + length pair, so in this case `str` is merely `char*`, nothing special.

I know that cross-platform development and dealing with baroque compiler environments can require a certain level of paranoia, but what, if any, justification is there for this double NULL check? I can't think of how the second clause would ever be true if the first wasn't, but I might be missing some unusual edge case.

Comment: C++ `nullptr` perhaps?

Comment: Looks like a bug. That `if` statement doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: GCC->g++ perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps it is intended like this? `if (combo->plugin.str == NULL || *combo->plugin.str == '\0')` To only dereference if not null?

Comment: @EdHeal I think using `nullptr` is the best plan when writing new code, but cross-platform concerns might prevent that from being a solution here. I'm just wondering what the second condition could ever hope to achieve.

Comment: @Galik That would make a lot more sense, testing for an empty string, but there's a `length` field there that can be checked, too. A missing `*` is probably the culprit here.

Comment: Well it is odd they do not simply check the length but looking at the source the comment above the line supports my thesis: *" If the plugin value in user table is found to be null or an empty string..."*

Comment: @Galik Thanks for the confirmation. If you want to add that as an answer, I think that's the best we can make of this.

Comment: It looks like they may have the same bug in other places too, comparing pointers to `'\0'`. It shows why we could have done with having a `nullptr` from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that the intention was to support the string where the  null termination is optional (therefore there is a length field). In this case, the invalid string that contains '\0' will have the **valid** size 1. That is why this sanity condition does not use the length. Anyway, there is a bug that makes the second condition always "true" and therefore pointless, the code probably shall look like:

```
if (combo->plugin.str == NULL || combo->plugin.str [0] == '\0')
```

Comment: That's probably the intention. What's odd is this pattern repeats itself through that code. Normally you'd define a macro or an inline function to help assert this properly. It's good that the compiler is rejecting this because it does seem to be an error. This is all based on the MySQL internals, so it's hard to tell the precise origin of this anti-pattern.

Comment: Now this bug is fixed (actually 8 days ago). Well, this is probably not the most idiomatic code you have seen.
There is actually a correct treating of this case in some other place in the code:
`const char *new_plugin= (combo->plugin.str && combo->plugin.str[0])`
I had checked the history, it seems that this specific line was copy - pasted from some other place. That is why this "patter" repeats itself.